# Export reports in QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, reports

I've created a report in QGIS 3.28.
Now I want to export this report to PDF using PyQGIS, but I can't find a method for it.

```
layout_manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
report = layout_manager.layoutByName("my_report")
settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
home_path = QgsProject.instance().homePath()
output = f"{home_path}/PDF/test.pdf"
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(report)
exporter.exportToPdf(output, settings)
```

This works just fine, when I use a created layout, but gives me an error at `exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(report)` when using the created report.

```
TypeError: QgsLayoutExporter(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsReport'
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsReport'
```

Obviously the `QgsLayoutExporter()` expects a `QgsLayout()` object, but my report is a `QgsReport()` object.
So how can I export a QgsReport?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `QgsLayoutExporter.exportToPdf` directly instead of making a `QgsLayoutExporter` object.

```py
layout_manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
report = layout_manager.layoutByName("my_report")
settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
home_path = QgsProject.instance().homePath()
output = f"{home_path}/PDF/test.pdf"

result, error = QgsLayoutExporter.exportToPdf(report, output, settings)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I actually tried this first, but had a typo. As a result, report was None and if report is None, QGIS crashes completely at the line result, error = QgsLayoutExporter.exportToPdf(report, output, settings). So now the first step is to check if the report is None.